# Truncated Icosahedron

Tags: mesh

I am attempting to create a truncated icosahedron (soccer ball) as specified in a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYC69tt-KMI). The tutorial shows this mesh being part of the Solids that are in Add-ons. Mesh>Solids>Archimedian>Truncated Icosahedron (see screenshot at 1:06 in tutorial). When I enable my add-ons, I do not see the same ones that he does. He's using v2.68 and I'm using v2.74. Have I done something wrong, or has it changed between versions?

Comment: Read one of the top comments for the tutorial written by Kyle Mayne: "1.When enabling addons select `Add Mesh` in the categories and check the box under "Add Mesh: Extra Objects"-the addon he is selected has been depreciated and merged into this.  2.Press `SHIFT` + `A` or use the menu and click on `Add` > `Mesh` > `Math Function` > `Solids` 3.On the left you'll notice you have settings for the mesh. Find where it says "Presets" and select "Truncated Icosahedron"."  And that really works.

Comment: Works great! Thank you -- I should have looked there before asking my question.

Answer (score 4):

In Object Mode hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut to add a new object, and in the menu select *Mesh>Icosphere* with number of subdivisions set to 1.

[image]

Then change to Edit Mode, select everything, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> shortcut to bevel the vertices and input 0.35 as the amount of bevel and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or in Bevel operator panel change amount type to Percent and change Amount to 33.333%

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think this can be solved even easier (though your soultion didn't work quite well for me). After adding `Icosphere` one should only change subdivisions level of it to 1 - http://i.imgur.com/d5cvHJa.jpg (left - `icosphere`, right - icosahedron from `Extra Objects` addon)

Comment: @MrZak yes I forgot to add that the subdivision of the icosphere have to be set to 1

Answer (score 2):

The plugin is called now **add_mesh_extra_objects**. To enable it press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open the preferences window. On the Addons tab type ***extra*** and and check the box for Add Mesh:Extra Objects

[image]

On the add menu you'll have the option Mesh-> Math_Function->Solid

[image]

Enable the Tool Shelf by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> (or press <kbd>F^</kbd>) and select Ichosahedron.

On the vertex truncation type 0.667

[image]