# How to create a tetrakaidecahedron and keep only the edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bmesh

[image: tetrakaidecahedron]

The idea I have is to start from the tetrakaidecahedron, have the edges and create something organical as the photomicrograph below.

[Photomicrograph of open-cell foamed urethane](https://www.are.na/block/1956859)
[image]

Comment: I'd use the [regular solids addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31727/2217) then the [wireframe modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a different method using the same Truncated Octahedron.

Under the user preferences make sure you activate the default bundled addon *Add Mesh Extra Objects*.

Add a new mesh of the type Math Function > Regular Solid and from the presets at the bottom pick Truncated Octahedron.

Erase the edges dividing the large faces in half, then add a *Skin* modifier on top of it.

Tick the *Smooth* option. On top of it add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

You can now extrude individual vertex to create the "protruding spike" structures of the linked cell.

[image]

Comment: Now I get it :) I didn't saw the image from link, have an UV!

Answer (score 7):

Under the user preferences make sure you activate the default bundled addon *Add Mesh Extra Objects*.

Add a new mesh of the type *Math Function > Regular Solid* and from the presets at the bottom pick *Truncated Octahedron*.

Erase the edges dividing the large faces in half, then add a *Wireframe* modifier.

Adjust the thickness as desired and add two *Subdivision* modifiers below it. The top one must be set to *Simple*, and the second one to *Catmull-Clark*.

Adjust subdivisions as desired for a more organic or geometric look.

[image]

Comment: I'm fighting with this one now - trying to find more automated way. It's a little bit trickier if you want to have flat external faces as in op image: https://imgur.com/GAFotvi

Comment: Indeed. It always bothered me that the *Wireframe* modifier doesn't have an option for that; one generally has to manually inset and solidify faces. But I assumed he wanted to create what's illustrated in the other picture so I ignored that fact.

Comment: Solidify is still not enough as internal faces will be the same as external. Really though one for automation. Manually you will need to delete middle internal edge and merge at center groups of 3 vertices to have the same mesh.

Comment: Yes it may result in self intersecting geometry, plus you have to "eyeball" the thickness values or end up with duplicate geometry.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos would u up to make a screen recording video tutorial ? I'm a beginner and I'm kind of struggeling. Would be amazing

Comment: There are two animations showing the process. What part are you stuck at, exactly?

Comment: https://www.are.na/block/2051402 This happens after I divided for an half and select edges loops + modifier skin or either wireframe! So I'm stuck there :) @Duart

Comment: Adjust vertex *Mean Radius* property from the 3D View Properties Area

Comment: unfortunately with all the computer I tried the program just crashed when i modify the vertex Mean Radius property ! Aaaa a pity @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: That's no good. Is your mesh too complex, or are you computers low end?