# Splitting a cylinder into two "branches"

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I'm brand new to blender and have been searching for tutorials or help in "branching" a cylinder into two.

I'm working a small tree branch segment - I've started with a cylinder, added some loop cuts, added a small extrusion as a smaller branch, but now I want the end of the cylinder to split into two.

Here's a 2D example of what I'm after:

[image]

The closest help I can find is [another post which mentions the pipe mesh plugin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12081/create-hollow-intersecting-tubes), but I already have my cylinder so I'm not sure this is the best approach.

There are plenty of L-joint pipe examples, but I don't want anything perpendicular, I want my one cylinder to branch into two.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/it-is-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-to-two-directions and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105072/how-is-possible-to-create-a-tetrakaidecahedron-how-can-i-keep-only-the-edges